# Decoding string to Japanese character in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, encode

I am fetching a report from MWS Amazon via https://github.com/python-amazon-mws/python-amazon-mws. But that report giving problem while fetching a report from Japanese market I have some SKU that have Japanese character in those and when I fetch and filter I will get SKU like 
`&#12521;&#12452;&#12488;&#12491;&#12531;&#12464;vtz-1843_MG`
instead of 
`ライトニングvtz-1843_MG`

I think I am doing something wrong in encoding/decoding please help.

```
report_data = reportsApi.get_report(report_id=report_id)
response = report_data.original
lines = response.decode("utf-8", "ignore").split("\n")

for line in lines:
    report_data = str(line).split("\t")
    sku = report_data[0].strip()
    print(sku)
```

Comment: The two strings appear the same. The Japanese characters appear just fine. SO like almost all sites since the late 90s uses UTF8 and the Japanese text appears just fine. What's the problem and why do you think you need to decode anything? If you have trouble searching in a database it may be the *database* text that's mangled or stored using the wrong encoding

Comment: Those are HTML entities that you need to HTML-decode…

Comment: If you use Unicode throughout you don't have to worry about languages (up to a point). The reason both Japanese and Greek text like Αυτό Εδώ appear just fine in SO is that it's built on .NET whose strings are Unicode, stores the data in nvarchar fields (ie Unicode) and returns the text as UTF8

Comment: OK, after the edit it's obvious those are HTML entities instead of UTF8 encoded text. This page itself shows that HTML encoding isn't necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python 2 :

```
>>> a = '&#12521;&#12452;&#12488;&#12491;&#12531;&#12464;vtz-1843_MG'
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> HTMLParser().unescape( a )
u'\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8\u30cb\u30f3\u30b0vtz-1843_MG'
>>> print HTMLParser().unescape( a )
ライトニングvtz-1843_MG
```

for python 3 :

```
>>> a = '&#12521;&#12452;&#12488;&#12491;&#12531;&#12464;vtz-1843_MG'
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape( a )
'ライトニングvtz-1843_MG'
```

Maybe python versions are not exact, but I could not `import html` in python 2, so it might have changed at some point, not sure where. But in your case one of the approaches should work (or both, if you're lucky =)